# Azure Dev Ops REST Api Get Agent.MachineName or ComputerName from Server 2019 or 5.0 for a Unix machine

Tags: unix, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2019

I am trying to get a list of the agents with the machines they are running on. I have successfully used the agents includeCapabilities option and have pulled the computer names of every other machine that is not UNIX with

```
$org/_apis/distributedtask/pools/$PoolId/agents?includeCapabilities=true&api-version=5.0 
$results = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -uri $url -Headers $headers
```

(I am using PowerShell to call the API)
I am however running into a problem where Unix machines do not have Agent.ComputerNames returned. The names do show up in Azure Dev Ops, so I know they exist.

I ran into the idea of getting the preset variable Agent.MachineName, but I can't find any documentation on getting access to the preset variables from the REST API. (A list of variables that are defined as useful to have access to, so I find it odd that you can't seem get them.)

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I found that Unix servers provide a NAME under systemCapabilities, while other servers provided a COMPUTERNAME. I had the issue since I was only looking for COMPUTERNAME. I found that it is better to grab the

agent.systemCapabilities.Agent.ComputerName property. In PowerShell

```
$agent.systemCapabilities."Agent.ComputerName"
```

the quotations are important to tell PowerShell that it is a one string not nested farther.